# What is the root path to a file on Windows? On MacOS?

Tags: python, windows, macos

I apologize for the simplicity of this question.  I'm learning to program in python, and my most recent task is learning to work with files.  Unfortunately I seem to be unable to correctly frame a path statement to open a specific file.  To make things even more interesting, I'm bi-OS-usal.  I work on both MacOS and Windows.

I've tried using the "os" module in python to generate an OS specific path that should work on either OS, but I continue to get FileNotFoundError.  Here's what I tried on the Mac.  Note that the path to the file is on the main drive (Macintosh HD) in the Users folder under my directory, toddb.  Filename is st.txt

```
import os
path = os.path.join("Users", "toddb", "st.txt")
stlaunch = open(path, "r")
```

At this point I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Since I didn't explicitly state the root drive I also tried:

```
path = os.path.join("Macintosh HD", "Users", "toddb", "st.txt")
```

Same error when I run my code.

Answer (score 2):

OSX has a single root called `/`. Windows has multiple roots (drives) called, for instance, `C:\\`. In python, you can reference the windows path with forward slashes as in `C:/`.

In either case, even though user directories have a default location, they can be moved around, making any hard and fast rule difficult. These operating systems usually put the home directory into environment variables which you can stitch together to find your home.

Python also has the `os.path.expanduser` function that does the heavy lifting for you. `expanduser('~')` expands the current user's home directory and `expanduser('~otheruser') gets others. Put it all together and you can do

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), "st.txt")
```

Comment: Internally, Windows also has a single ``\`` root, but for the object namespace instead of a file system. It's laid out for use by the system and drivers rather than users. It has a few fixed directory and object names plus a lot of automatically numbered and GUID names. The common device names are symbolic links, e.g. the "C:" drive is `\Global??\C:` => `\Device\HarddiskVolume[N]`, where [N] could be any number but it's typically 1 or 2, and the HKLM registry hive is `\Registry\Machine`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Very helpful.  Unfortunately I'm still getting the file not found error.  Here's my latest:
'code'
    >>> path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Python.txt")
    >>> path
    'C:\\Users\\Todd\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python\\Python.txt'
    >>> stlaunch = open(path, "r")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    stlaunch = open(path, "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Todd\\Python.txt'

Answer (score 0):

The root directory is named `/`. Put that at the beginning:

```
path = os.path.join("/", "Users", "toddb", "st.txt")
```